# PowerShell SOAP Request XML NameSpace setup

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell, soap, namespaces

I am trying to parse SOAP/XML response with PowerShell.
How to I setup the namespace for the request and response?
How do I parse through the SOAP Envelope?

I believe that I'm not understanding how to manage the namespace and properly deal with the SOAP Envelope.  I am working with an API that provides the format of a request and response:

Here is the template for the SOAP 1.2 request:

```
POST /LinkPlusWebService/WsIncident.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: server.domain.net
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <FindIncidents4Customer xmlns="http://www.techexcel.com/">
      <LinkedSystemID>string</LinkedSystemID>
      <LinkedProjectID>string</LinkedProjectID>
      <lProjectID>int</lProjectID>
      <lCustomerID>int</lCustomerID>
    </FindIncidents4Customer>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Here is the template for the SOAP 1.2 response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <FindIncidents4CustomerResponse xmlns="http://www.techexcel.com/">
      <FindIncidents4CustomerResult>string</FindIncidents4CustomerResult>
    </FindIncidents4CustomerResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

XML parsing returned that entire string only.The sting returned in string looks like:

```
<ID>298343</ID><TITLE>This is free text-that may contain / any character . . . </TITLE><ID>192723</ID><TITLE>Loreum Ipsum</TITLE><ID>298343</ID><TITLE>Thanks for help</TITLE><ID>192723</ID><TITLE>Strings are hard</TITLE>
```

In PowerShell, how can I get each "ID" element into an array of strings.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <FindIncidents4CustomerResponse xmlns="http://www.techexcel.com/">
      <FindIncidents4CustomerResult>
      <ID>298343</ID><TITLE>This is free text-that may contain / any character . . . </TITLE><ID>192723</ID><TITLE>Loreum Ipsum</TITLE><ID>298343</ID><TITLE>Thanks for help</TITLE><ID>192723</ID><TITLE>Strings are hard</TITLE>
      </FindIncidents4CustomerResult>
    </FindIncidents4CustomerResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

How to I setup the namespace for the request and response?
How do I parse through the SOAP Envelope?

Comment: Should that be `<TITLE>This is free text-that may contain / any character . . . </TITLE>` with a closing `</TITLE>` tag, or is your above posting correct?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction.  I've edited the post the "</TITLE>" tags should have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetElementsByTagName method to get the array of ID nodes.

```
[xml]$XML = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <FindIncidents4CustomerResponse xmlns="http://www.techexcel.com/">
      <FindIncidents4CustomerResult>
      <ID>298343</ID><TITLE>This is free text-that may contain / any character . . . </TITLE><ID>192723</ID><TITLE>Loreum Ipsum</TITLE><ID>298343</ID><TITLE>Thanks for help</TITLE><ID>192723</ID><TITLE>Strings are hard</TITLE>
      </FindIncidents4CustomerResult>
    </FindIncidents4CustomerResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
"@
$IDs = $xml.GetElementsByTagName("ID").'#text'
```

That would set `$IDs` to:

```
298343
192723
298343
192723
```

**Edit:** Ok, if that doesn't work let's work with the string that was kicked back. This one:

```
<ID>298343</ID><TITLE>This is free text-that may contain / any character . . . </TITLE><ID>192723</ID><TITLE>Loreum Ipsum</TITLE><ID>298343</ID><TITLE>Thanks for help</TITLE><ID>192723</ID><TITLE>Strings are hard</TITLE>
```

You just want the ID numbers? Set the string to a variable, let's say `$IDString`. Then we run that against a regex search, and from each match we select the value of the matched text.

```
$IDs = ([regex]"<ID>(.+?)</ID>").matches($IDString)|%{$_.Groups[1].value}
```

Now `$IDs` now contains the 4 ID numbers as above.

Comment: That looks great and but the [xml] HTTP response doesn't return anything for GetElementsByTagName.  The SOAP envelope seems to treat that one line as string not a collection of elements.  Is there a way to unpackage the XML from within the SOAP envelope?  Is the response behaving oddly because of the namespaces? I am honestly uncertain what the namespace does to parsing.

Comment: In my `soap` response, I have `[xml]$xml = $xml.Content` and get no output with `$xml`, and with `$xml.GetType()`: `System.Xml.XmlDocument`. When `$xml = $xml.Content;$xml` I get the xml output `<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>..` and as type `string`. How can I parse? New question on SO?